# Set tabs in settings on Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, settings

I would like to add tabs in setting page in my plugin. I have the following code in `/[myplugin]/templates/_setting.html`. However, the tabs do not show up, does anyone have any sample code to set up the tabs? Thanks

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{% set tabs = {
customer: { label: "Customer"|t, url: url('emailUser/_settings') },
veterinarian:    { label: "Veterinarian"|t, url: url('emailUser/_vetSettings') }
} %}

{{ forms.textField({
label: "Customer Account Creation Confirmation Subject"|t,
instructions: "Customer Account Creation Confirmation Subject" |t,
name: 'custAccountCreationSubject',
value: settings.custAccountCreationSubject,
})}}

{{ forms.textareaField({
label: "Customer Account Creation Confirmation Message"|t,
instructions: "Customer email message when customer register" |t,
name: 'custAccountCreation',
value: settings.custAccountCreation,
rows:10,
})}}
```

In `myplugin.php`

```
public function getSettingsHtml()
{
    return craft()->templates->render('emailuser/_settings',array(
                'settings'=>$this->getSettings()
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here’s a simple plugin with two tabs and two fields, one field per tab. This plugin was generated on https://pluginfactory.io/. It’s a great starting point to get the plugin scaffolding set up. After that I added the code that I’ve included below to get it to work.

It should give you something like the following screenshot for the first tab:

[image: First tab of plugin]

and for the second tab it should look similar to this:

[image: Second tab of plugin]

## Folder Structure

```
[-] craft
   [-] plugins
      [-] myplugin
         [-] controllers
            |-- MyPlugin_TabOneController.php
            |-- MyPlugin_TabTwoController.php
         [+] resources
         [+] services
         [-] templates
            [-] _layouts
               |-- cp.twig
            [-] tabOne
               |-- _index.twig
            [-] tabTwo
               |-- _index.twig
         [+] translations
         [+] variables
         |-- MyPluginPlugin.php
```

---

### `myplugin/MyPluginPlugin.php`

I'm only highlighting the functions that were necessary for the plugins to show up. Add or adjust them as needed.

```php
...

public function registerCpRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'myplugin' => ['action' => "myPlugin/tabOne/index"],
        'myplugin/additional-settings' => ['action' => "myPlugin/tabTwo/index"],
        /**
         * Each 'action' relates to a controller in your plugin.
         * The names of your controller and these action must match.
         */
    );
}

protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
        'someSetting' => array(AttributeType::String, 'label' => 'Some Setting', 'default' => ''),
        'additionalSetting' => array(AttributeType::String, 'label' => 'Some Additional Setting', 'default' => ''),
        /*...more settings here as needed...*/
    );
}

public function getSettingsHtml()
{
   return craft()->templates->render('myplugin/MyPlugin_Settings', array(
       'settings' => $this->getSettings()
   ));
}

public function getSettingsUrl()
{
    return 'myplugin';
    /* This must be the same as the first segment in your cpRoutes. */
}

...
```

---

### `myplugin/controllers/MyPlugin_TabOneController.php`

```php
namespace Craft;

class MyPlugin_TabOneController extends BaseController
{

    /**
     * @var    bool|array Allows anonymous access to this controller's actions.
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $allowAnonymous = array('actionIndex',
        );

    /**
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $settings = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myPlugin')->getSettings();
        $this->renderTemplate('myplugin/tabOne/_index', array(
            'settings' => $settings,
        ));
        /**
         * The path above is to your templates folder in your plugin.
         */
    }
}
```

---

### `myplugin/controllers/MyPlugin_TabTwoController.php`

```php
namespace Craft;

class MyPlugin_TabTwoController extends BaseController
{

    /**
     * @var    bool|array Allows anonymous access to this controller's actions.
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $allowAnonymous = array('actionIndex',
        );

    /**
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $settings = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myPlugin')->getSettings();
        $this->renderTemplate('myplugin/tabTwo/_index', array(
            'settings' => $settings,
        ));
        /**
         * The path above is to your templates folder in your plugin.
         */
    }
}
```

---

### `myplugin/templates/_layouts/cp.twig`

It’s not necessary to break out the templates like I have here but it does help to keep from repeating your self in the templates, especially if you have several tabs.

```twig
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{% includeCssResource "myplugin/css/Myplugin_Style.css" %}
{% includeJsResource "myplugin/js/Myplugin_Script.js" %}

{% set title = 'My Plugin' %}

{% set tabs = {
    settings: { label: "Settings"|t, url: url('myplugin') },
    additionalSettings: { label: "Additional Settings"|t, url: url('myplugin/additional-settings') },
} %}
```

---

### `myplugin/templates/tabOne/_index.twig`

The `data-saveshortcut` attribute on the form will allow you to use the keyboard shortcut to save your plugin’s settings by using <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd> on a Mac. I’m assuming that <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> works on Windows although I haven’t tried it.

```twig
{% extends "myplugin/_layouts/cp" %}
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{% set selectedTab = 'settings' %}

{% set content %}

    <h2>Settings</h2>

    <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-saveshortcut data-confirm-unload>

        {{ getCsrfInput() }}

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="plugins/savePluginSettings">
        <input type="hidden" name="pluginClass" value="MyPlugin">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="myplugin">

        {{ forms.textField({
            label: 'Some Setting',
            instructions: 'Enter some setting here.',
            id: 'settings-someSetting',
            name: 'settings[someSetting]', 
            value: settings['someSetting']})
        }}

        <div class="buttons">
            <input class="btn submit" type="submit" value="{{ 'Save'|t }}">
        </div>

    </form>

{% endset %}
```

---

### `myplugin/templates/tabOne/_index.twig`

Notice that you’ll need to set the `selectedTab` in each template for the tabs to work correctly. This should match one of your keys that was set in the `tabs` variable in the `myplugin/templates/_layouts/cp.twig`. Also the hidden `redirect` input in the form should be set to wherever you want to it end up. I noticed that it felt the best when it went back to the original page and it showed the saved values.

```twig
{% extends "myplugin/_layouts/cp" %}
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{% set selectedTab = 'additionalSettings' %}

{% set content %}

    <h2>Additional Settings</h2>

    <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-saveshortcut data-confirm-unload>

        {{ getCsrfInput() }}

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="plugins/savePluginSettings">
        <input type="hidden" name="pluginClass" value="MyPlugin">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="myplugin/additional-settings">

        {{ forms.textField({
            label: 'Some Additional Setting',
            instructions: 'Enter some setting here.',
            id: 'settings-additionalSetting',
            name: 'settings[additionalSetting]', 
            value: settings['additionalSetting']})
        }}

        <div class="buttons">
            <input class="btn submit" type="submit" value="{{ 'Save'|t }}">
        </div>

    </form>

{% endset %}
```

That should do it!

Comment: the return for getSettingsHtml() does seem to be correct. Where do I have to link here or what to return.

Comment: Oh ok. I was on the wrong track. I still used the old URL in my browser. But what about the getSettingHTML -> I think it is not needed, because defined other routes and templates